# this property interactivity is triggering for all individual component instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to toggle the interactivity on an emit event to only trigger that *specific* component instance, but when I click, it emits to all. For example:

```
// Favorite.vue
    export default {

        props: ['reply'],

        data() {
            return {
                isFavorited: this.reply.isFavorited,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            toggle() {
                if (this.isFavorited) {
                    axios.delete('/replies/' + this.reply.id + '/favorites');
                    this.isFavorited = false;
                    window.events.$emit("selfRemoveLike", 1);
                } else {
                    axios.post('/replies/' + this.reply.id + '/favorites');
                    this.isFavorited = true;
                    window.events.$emit("selfAddLike", 1);
                }    
            }
        }
    }

// Reply.vue
        created() {

            window.events.$on('selfAddLike', (data) => {
                this.isFavorited = true;
                this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount + data;
                window.events.$emit('showAddLike');
            });

            window.events.$on('selfRemoveLike', (data) => {
                this.isFavorited = false;
                this.favoritesCount = this.favoritesCount - data;
                window.events.$emit('showRemoveLike');
            });
        },
```

How can I make it so it only triggers for a single component and not update the every single  component to have isFavorited triggered.

Comment: How and where are you triggering this from? why are you listening on window instead of a parent component?

Comment: Yes I am listening on window instead of parent component. I'm new to Vue so it's kind of confusing. I thought *this* would refer to the specific Reply component, but all Reply components are updated!

Comment: If you can and it won't break your app flow, use vue emitters. Change `window.events.$on...` for methods and inside those methods call `this.$emit('eventName', value)`

Comment: I updated my code to reflect that the Reply.vue file is listening from the Favorite.vue. What would the listener look like? $this.on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: using this.$parent.$emit as the sender (child component), and $this.on as the consumer (parent component)...

I guess the window.events captured everything, where as with the solution above it targeted the specific component. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Vue.js. It's some kind of third party event bus library.

Also, if you emit events, and listen for them, callback will be called. Don't listen in the components you don't want callbacks to be ran at.

Comment: The situation is that I have the same component rendered multiple times and all of them are being updated upon *this* update, which I am assuming to be for that one specific component. I.E. I have multiple Reply components during the render

Comment: I would need code examples of the components that are listening for those events. Right now it's extremely hard to say anything.